# Remove explicit recursion from function with dependent values

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have the following Haskell function which uses explicit recursion:

```
f :: [a] -> [a]
f (a:b:xs) = g a b : f (g a b : xs)
  where
    g :: a -> a -> a
f (_:[])   = []
f []       = []
```

Note that the recursive call depends on the value calculated in the step before (by `g`).

Is there a way to remove the explicit recursion and if so, how?

Comment: What are the base case(s)?

Comment: Please see my edit. I think I added them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your function is exactly a fold that emits intermediate values. In Haskell this is called a [scan](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/List_processing#Scans). Specifically, [scanl1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3ascanl1) is equivalent to your `f` except the first element.

```
f = drop 1 . scanl1 g
```

Comment: And I need the `tail` because otherwise it would be `f (a:b:xs) = a : g a b : f (g a b : xs)`, right?

Comment: Sven, Something like that. scanl1 outputs the first element raw without applying g, while your f skips it. Ganesh, I'll fix that. Forgot that tail can't work on empty lists.

Answer (score -3):

use tail recursion, ghc can optimaze it

```
f (a:b:xs) acc = f (g a b : xs) (g a b : acc)
f _ acc = reverse acc
```

and call so

```
f myList []
```